# "Muse on" vs. "muse about"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

I came across the verb *muse*, which roughly means to be absorbed in thought about any given thing. I wondered, when specifying what someone was musing about, would it be better to say:

> I muse about what happened that day.

Or:

> I muse on what happened that day.

Which is correct, or better?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*[Muse](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/muse_2)* can be used with *about*, *on*, *over* or *upon* and they all mean essentially the same.

Comment: It will be good to know if this applies to "Notes on X" VS "Notes about X". I don't really want to ask a question if this advice applies.

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible; *muse on* is more common than *muse about*. Also, muse on is more focused and specific, and muse about is more general.

Answer (score 2):

Muse on [this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=muse+over%2C+muse+on%2C+muse+about%2C+muse+upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Also, *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* says this about the matter:

[image]

Still, I think it might come down to *what* you're musing on or about.

For example [*muse on the day*](http://www.google.com/#q=%22muse+on+the+day%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=mEE3UK6yJafRyQH1iIC4Dg&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAA&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=74b92fcf2d6b4d8b&biw=1675&bih=870) returned only one hit in Google books, while [*muse about the day*](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&prmdo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22muse+about+the+day%22&oq=%22muse+about+the+day%22&gs_l=serp.3...126913.129374.2.130380.7.7.0.0.0.4.269.1161.2j3j2.7.0...0.0...1c.KfuIlptp6R0&pbx=1&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=74b92fcf2d6b4d8b&biw=1675&bih=870) returns at least four.  I might be more inclined to say *muse about* when the object of my musing is less focused – I mused *on* my predicament, yet I mused *about* my day – but you would be foolish to regard that as a hard and fast rule.

Incidentally, if you restrict the Ngram to [more recent sources](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=muse+over%2Cmuse+on%2Cmuse+about%2Cmuse+upon&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it seems to contradict the usage note in M-W, meaning *about* might be becoming more like *upon* and *over*, with *on* remaining the frontrunner. (That said, it's a silly notion to think that you should always follow what Ngram shows is most common. Muse on that advice for awhile.)

Answer (score 1):

OED gives a few options:   [Usu. with about, in, of, on, over, upon.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/124061?rskey=M6yzur&result=6#eid)

The 'in' is rare and archaic, and I have also heard "muse up", as in "the guitarist can always muse up a new tune", which I hope will remain rare and soon become archaic.